# Generating key in PuTTYgen takes too long/never finishes

Tags: ssh, putty, ssh-keys

I am using puttygen.exe (the one from https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html)  to generate a RSA key. However, several hours have passed and it still has not finished

[image]

How much time does it normally take to generate a RSA key, and why does it take hours in my case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you follow the instructions on the dialog:

> Please generate some randomness by **moving the mouse over the blank area**.

Generating the key takes little time. Generation of randomness takes longer, but still it takes few seconds only (you have to keep moving the mouse, until the progress bar reaches the end).

Comment: Thank you, I had a time leaving it there running for hours, and was wondering why it became not working, I must have moved my mouse for my previous usage which generated the public key fairly fast.